# Append another checkbox cuase the previous checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, css

the form is a To_do list with html/css/javascript and each row has a checkbox based on completed task or uncompleted task.
I create an event. It takes some value from an object such as text, created at, id, ... and finally append a li tag to the  with **inner HTML+=`...`** . If i checked the previous checkbox in

but when raise an event (press a button) the new row added unchecked(it is ok) but the previous row's checkbox was unchecked!?

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some detail. If you want help with your code, it's impossible for anyone to help you if you don't show the code you want help with. In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76889216/edit) and add some code to your question.

Comment: Rather than updating the contents of the unordered-list by setting all elements by updating the `innerHTML`, consider updating the list by adding a single item to it, by using `ulElement.appendChild` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

When you set the innerHTML, all of the elements are destroyed and then re-created. If you haven't captured which elements were checked before this step, you create a list of unchecked items. Basically, the HTML is not updated to reflect the 'checked' state - that state is maintained internally by the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick snippet which replicates your problem.
Run it, then inspect-element on the checkbox. Notice how checking/unchecking the box doesn't change the html you're inspecting?

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
    document.getElementById('addNewBtn').addEventListener('click', onAddBtnClick, false);
}

function onAddBtnClick(evt)
{
    let newStr = "<li><input type='checkbox'/></li>";
    document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML += newStr;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li><input type='checkbox'/></li>
    </ul>
    <button id='addNewBtn'>Add new Item</button>
```

Here's an alternate snippet which adds a single item to the end of the list.

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
    document.getElementById('addNewBtn').addEventListener('click', onAddBtnClick2, false);
}

function onAddBtnClick2(evt)
{
    let newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox'/>";
    document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(newLi);
}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li><input type='checkbox'/></li>
    </ul>
    <button id='addNewBtn'>Add new Item</button>
```